# Can I post a guide on SO as a question?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, asking-questions, scope

I want to post a guide or a collection of learning resources on how to get started with developing for Windows Phone 7. Is it okay to start a guide by clicking ASK QUESTION button even though it's not really a question? Will I get down-ranked for that?

Comment: Huh, go figure, I was about to make a Meta post inquiring what should be done about [this kind of non-question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983194/sharepoint-state-machine-workflow-walkthrough). Guess this works just fine.

Comment: @ccomet: exactly what I did...made a comment on the question on what the OP should do. Can be flagged for moderator attention only because I don't have enough rep to vote to close.

Comment: Check out the original SO question -- an answer was added after the migration, that remains undeleted.

Answer (score 7):

Asking a question that's *not* a question will probably get it closed as "not a question". Asking a question that *is* a question, then answering it yourself, is acceptable.

Comment: +1, this is inline with the FAQ: "It's also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question, but pretend you're on Jeopardy: phrase it in the form of a question."

Comment: +1: the only issue I see is that the guide needs to be small enough to fit into the SO answer.  There is an upper limit (around 32KB, IIRC).